# Specify greater than or equal to Git tag in requirements.txt

Tags: python, git, pip

In my requirements.txt I'd like to specify that I need greater than or equal to a specific version of a Python dependency. I could do this if I wanted the dependency Python package installed from PyPI:

```
ExamplePackage>=0.2
```

But what if I want to specify the GitHub URL to install from? I know you can specify an exact tag:

```
-e git://github.com/my-username/ExamplePackage.git@v0.2
```

But can I specify a >= instead?

Comment: I doubt you can do this with requirements.txt / pip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, unfortunately.

See the [list of supported git specifications in the official doc](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#git)s, none of which allow for >=

Seems like it would be useful functionality for somebody to add, though

Comment: Thanks, I think it would be a useful addition.